# Error inflating class <unknown> Android Samsung Modding

Tags: android, xml

For some reason, every time I try to add an image into SystemUi, it ends up force closing on me. Here are the xmls that should be controlling it:

tw_status_bar_expanded

```
LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/notificationCart" android:background="#ff000000" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_expanded_notification_category_height">
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageView android:layout_gravity="left|center" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:padding="2.0dip" android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_expanded_notification_category_height" android:src="@drawable/notification_accent" android:scaleType="fitXY" />
                    <TextView android:textSize="@dimen/status_bar_expanded_notification_category_text_size" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@color/notification_category_color" android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/latestNotificationText" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="@string/status_bar_latest_events_title" android:layout_alignParentLeft="false" />
                    <ImageView android:layout_gravity="right|center" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:padding="2.0dip" android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_expanded_notification_category_height" android:src="@drawable/notification_accent" android:scaleType="fitXY" />
               </LinearLayout>
```

public.xml

```
<public type="drawable" name="notification_accent" id="0x7f020229" />
```

ids.xml

```
<item type="id" name="notification_accent">false</item>
```

With a SMALI declaration in R$Drawable:

```
.field public static final notification_accent:I = 0x7f020229
```

I know, I'm sorry, the formatting is atrocious. That one I can honestly blame on Samsung.

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 5835): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.android.systemui.SystemUIService: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class <unknown>

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2414)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:140)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class <unknown>

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:16434)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.makeStatusBarView(PhoneStatusBar.java:539)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.addStatusBarWindow(PhoneStatusBar.java:3098)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.createAndAddWindows(PhoneStatusBar.java:3067)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.start(BaseStatusBar.java:456)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.start(PhoneStatusBar.java:488)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at com.android.systemui.SystemUIService.onCreate(SystemUIService.java:94)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2404)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    ... 10 more

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    ... 32 more

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020229 a=-1 r=0x7f020229}

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1925)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5835):    ... 35 more

E/android.os.Debug( 2422): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error

W/ActivityManager( 2422): Process com.android.systemui has crashed too many times: killing!
```

What I find particularly interesting is...

```
 E/AndroidRuntime( 5835): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020229 a=-1 r=0x7f020229}
```

Even though it has been declared. I have not even the slightest as to why it is crashing out...

Comment: the same id should be also in resources, they may have changed while playing with resources, try apktool d the resulting apk (within a new directory), public.xml it's only a dump, it's not used as input

Comment: what do you mean in resources? I have the image file in drawable-xhdpi, if thats what you are referring to.

Comment: I suppose you are using apktool, did you added the additional touchwiz framework? public.xml is not used while packaging, you should pick the resulting apk, unpack it and check what's wrong

Comment: I did add in the additional framework. I will try decompiling the compiled file and poke around in there a bit.

Comment: Well how strange. It changed it over to an id, rather than a drawable. Though I don't know why or how?

EDIT: Nevermind. It added an id for it and changed the declaration.